# Is there a way to `Merge` with different functions across Keys?

Tags: dataset, gathering

Many times when working with `Dataset` I have to `GroupBy`. If for example, I group by and aggregate on columns of the same type then the single aggregator function like the following is usually enough.

```
GroupBy[dataset,First->Rest,Total]
```

which is equivalent to

```
GroupBy[dataset,First->Rest,Merge[Total]]
```

If my `Rest` is all numeric columns then the `Total` works fine on them. But now let's say I am encountering a case where my `Rest` is columns of `DateObject`, `Number` and `Entity` among other things.

Now `Total`, when applied to columns of `DateObject` and `Entities`, don't produce meaningful results.

So I am looking for a way to use a `Merge` which can have different aggregators for different keys.

```
GroupBy[dataset,First->Rest,Merge[...]]
```

Is there a form of `Merge` or some other equivalent function that applies a different aggregator based on the keys? Like for example:

```
Merge[<|"DateColumn"->Max,"NumberColumn"->Total,"EntityColumn"->First|>]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways:

```
data = AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"}, #] & /@ Tuples[{1, 2}, {3}]
(* {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 2|>,
    <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 2|>,
    <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 2|>,
    <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 2|>} *)

GroupBy[data, First -> Rest, Merge[Apply@Construct]@*Prepend[<|"b" -> b, "c" -> c|>]]
(* <|1 -> <|"b" -> b[1, 1, 2, 2], "c" -> c[1, 2, 1, 2]|>,
     2 -> <|"b" -> b[1, 1, 2, 2], "c" -> c[1, 2, 1, 2]|>|> *)

GroupBy[data, First -> Rest, Query[{"b" -> b, "c" -> c}]@*Merge[Identity]]
(* <|1 -> <|"b" -> b[{1, 1, 2, 2}], "c" -> c[{1, 2, 1, 2}]|>,
     2 -> <|"b" -> b[{1, 1, 2, 2}], "c" -> c[{1, 2, 1, 2}]|>|> *)
```

The first one prepends an additional association to the associations to be merged. It then uses [`Construct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Construct.html) to apply the function from the first association to the elements of the other associations.

The second approach merges the associations with `Identity`, and uses `Query` to apply the appropriate post-processing to each entry. In my opinion, this one is more readable. It also has the advantage that it doesn't break if the associations have keys not present in your "reduction list":

```
GroupBy[data, First -> Rest, Merge[Apply@Construct]@*Prepend[<|"b" -> b|>]]
(* <|1 -> <|"b" -> b[1, 1, 2, 2], "c" -> 1[2, 1, 2]|>,
     2 -> <|"b" -> b[1, 1, 2, 2], "c" -> 1[2, 1, 2]|>|> *)

GroupBy[data, First -> Rest, Query[{"b" -> b}]@*Merge[Identity]]
(* <|1 -> <|"b" -> b[{1, 1, 2, 2}], "c" -> {1, 2, 1, 2}|>,
     2 -> <|"b" -> b[{1, 1, 2, 2}], "c" -> {1, 2, 1, 2}|>|> *)
```

Notice how the first output contains expressions like `1[2, 1, 2]` (since we didn't supply a function in the first association, `Construct` simply took the element from the first "proper" association for the head - in this case a `1`). The second output simply contains `{1, 2, 1, 2}` in that place, since the output from `Merge` has just been left untouched.

Comment: Thank you Lukas for your answer. I was reusing this technique in another code today and thought if there was a way to instead of defining actual keys one could define patterns so could bundle them, like `Query[{"a"|b"->f,"c"->g}]`. But it is not working do you know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: @user13892 Unfortunately, I am not aware of a nice built-in way to achieve that. I can think of a few ugly ways, but maybe it's better if you ask a new question about this part specifically, chances are good that someone else can think of a nice solution

Comment: Thank you, I have asked this specific question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217033/does-anyone-know-a-way-to-use-patterns-in-query)

Answer (score 7):

I created a [Wolfram repository function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MergeByKey) specifically for this. It allows you to define different functions for merging different keys. For example, you can merge numerical and categorical columns with different functions in the Titanic dataset:

```
data = Normal @ ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];
ResourceFunction["MergeByKey"][data,
  {"age" -> Histogram},
  BarChart[Counts[#], ChartLabels -> Automatic] &
]
```

[image]

`MergeByKey` is based on `AssociationTranspose` (from the `GeneralUtilities` package) and `Query`. It's also worth noting that it's significantly faster on large rectangular datasets like the one from the example:

```
merge1 = ResourceFunction["MergeByKey"][data, {}]; // RepeatedTiming
merge2 = Merge[data, Identity]; // RepeatedTiming
merge1 === merge2
```

> {0.0054, Null}

> {0.022, Null}

> True

Comment: This function is awesome. Thanks Sjoerd!

Comment: Many thanks for this useful function!